# Remove element row using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have a table that looks like this:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Somthing</td>
        <td>Somthing</td>
        <td><span><a href="#" data-id="45" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs delete" data-title="Delete"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span></a></span></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

When the button is clicked the row is deleted from database using this jQuery script:

```
$('.delete').click(function() {
    swal({
        title: "Sure you want to delete?",
        text: "Point of no return",
        type: "warning",
        showCancelButton: true,
        confirmButtonColor: "#DD6B55",
        confirmButtonText: "Yes, delete",
        closeOnConfirm: false
    }, function() {

        swal("Success!", "Entry deleted!", "success");

        var data = ({
            'id': $('.delete').data("id"),
            'table': 'tablename',
            'img_root': 'images',
            'affiliated_table': 0,
            'affiliated_tablename': ''
        });

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/libs/delete.php",
            data: data,
            cache: false,
            success: function(html) {
                $('.delete').closest('tr').fadeOut('slow');
            }
        })
    });
})
```

I'm using the sweetalert as a check before calling AJAX, that will delete the entry from db. this all works very well, but i also want the actual row to be deleted. Once this is done the user should be able to see the changes in realtime. What happens now is that it actually deletes all the rows, i have tryed to change the .delete with this, without any success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```js
$('.delete').click(function() {

  var self = this;
  swal({
    title: "Sure you want to delete?",
    text: "Point of no return",
    type: "warning",
    showCancelButton: true,
    confirmButtonColor: "#DD6B55",
    confirmButtonText: "Yes, delete",
    closeOnConfirm: false
  }, function() {

    swal("Success!", "Entry deleted!", "success");

    var data = ({
      'id': $('.delete').data("id"),
      'table': 'tablename',
      'img_root': 'images',
      'affiliated_table': 0,
      'affiliated_tablename': ''
    });

    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "/libs/delete.php",
      data: data,
      cache: false,
      success: function(html) {
        //$('.delete').closest('tr').fadeOut('slow');
        $(self).closest('tr').fadeOut('slow')
      }
    })
  });
})
```

Comment: One thing that come to my atention is that this allways deletes the first entry in the row, and not the one selected, if i have 3 rows in table, it will still delete nr 1

Comment: in `data` use `$(self).data("id")` in place of `$('.delete').data("id")`

Answer (score 2):

You can use `this` to reference the delete button which raised the event and find the nearest `tr` from there. Try this:

```
$('.delete').click(function() {
    var $delete = $(this);

    // your code...

    var data = {
        'id': $delete.data("id"), // note use of $delete here
        'table': 'tablename',
        'img_root': 'images',
        'affiliated_table': 0,
        'affiliated_tablename': ''
    };

    $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url:"/libs/delete.php",
        data:data,
        cache: false,
        success:function(html){
            $delete.closest('tr').fadeOut('slow', function(){
               $(this).remove();
            }); // note use of $delete here
        }
    })
})
```